# How to delete last 6 characters from a column in .xlsx file using R?

Tags: r, xlsx

I have an .xlsx file with 845 rows and 61 columns, and one of the columns is a list of location names. Each cell in this column, however, ends with six unwanted characters like ' (001)', ' (014)' ' (013)', etc..., having a space, brackets and numbers, which i want to delete. Also, the header does not have this issue and I need all other columns intact, so these should not be affected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV7wZ.png)

I can do this in MS Excel with the following formula

=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-6)

(https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-can-i-remove-the-last-5-characters-from-a-cell.272639/)

But i want to do it in R. (PS - am an amateur at R)

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting the last n characters from a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963898/extracting-the-last-n-characters-from-a-string-in-r). e.g., looking at [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7964027/17303805) you would just use `end = -6` instead of `start = -6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest looking at the answer from another post:

[How to remove last n characters from every element in the R vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413331/how-to-remove-last-n-characters-from-every-element-in-the-r-vector)

I adapted the solution from @nfmcclure to your situation.

```
#Example dataframe 
df <- structure(list(location = c("Akola (001)", "Jamkhed (014)", "Karjat (013)", 
                                  "Kopargaeon (003)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                            -4L))
#Solution
substr(df$location,1,nchar(df$location)-5)
```